# Disadvantages and advantages of using typescript with Angular 1.6

Tags: angularjs, typescript

We have a big project that currently runs in angular 1.4 version. We are integrating now Webpack, Typescript and Angular 1.6 version to be migration ready for angular 2/4.

We realize the advantages of bringing Webpack instead of our own build/bundling system. Angular 1.6 is also necessary step towards angular 2.

We do not have yet ES6. So we use ES5.

So question is: What are the advantages and disadvantages of integrating typescript with angular 1.6?

The question is not about whether typescript itself brings to us, but how clean, easy and less problematic for developers would be to have typescript with angularjs.

Really appreciate for sharing your experiences of using typescript with Angularjs.

EDIT: Cons we have found so far: Type Definition, Finding help will be a challenge, extra overhead of transpiling (sometime could very long), convinsing developers are hard because of lack of resources to get help.

Best,

Comment: *" but how clean, easy and less problematic for developers would be to have typescript with angularjs"* Those all sound like opinions.

Answer (score 0):

I worked with TS + Angular 1.6 combo, and TS can help all areas of the code, except the html templates of course. You can iteratively migrate to TS, one file after the other. TS is will not slow you down. When you write the code, you know how your objects, services, controllers look like, so it shouldn't be a problem to write the types after the variables. The code completion it brings in VSCode or Atom, etc, are very helpful. I usually wrote interfaces for the scope of a component/directive, so it was easy to see what the controller see on the angular scope. Also with TS you will be able to use features like async/await, and that can really clean up codes with lots of promises for example.
But I'm a little biased towards TS because I'm coming from the Java world and TS was easier for me than plain JS.

Comment: Thanks. Did you have many external libraries? Does one need to to bring tep definitions for them?